# Getting a reference to the AsCached property in the ObjectContext for Entity Framework 4.1

Tags: caching, entity-framework-4.1

I have my ObjectContext exposed as a public property and am able to access it via my DBContext.

I want to enable caching for a drop down list. It requires the **AsCached** property. However, I can't get it to display in the intellisense. Do I need to include a specific namespace for it?

Here is my existing LINQ statement that I want cached.

```
IQueryable<Category> category = DbContext.Categories.Where(p => p.CategoryID > 0);
```

I'm tying to do something like this. Note though, that there is **no** intellisense when placing the "." after Objectcontext.

```
IQueryable<Category> category = DbContext.Objectcontext.Categories.AsCached.Where(p => p.CategoryID > 0);
```

The ObjectContext pops up in the intellisense, but not the AsCached property.

**How can I get the AsCached property to appear?**

Comment: I don't see an `AsCached` property on [`ObjectContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.aspx)

Comment: Have I answered your question?  I am interested to know if you now can get the AsCached behavior that you want.

Answer (score 1):

Are you referring to the AsCached property described here [Getting a reference to the AsCached property](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/adodotnetentityframework/thread/01bba85c-93d9-4d53-af84-e516a027fb32)?  In which case it seems to be an extension to the EF called [linqtocache](http://code.google.com/p/linqtocache/).

### EDIT

I do not think you need to expose ObjectContext.  Say you have a DbContext that looks like this:

```
public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
{
    public DatabaseContext(string name) : base(name)
    {
        As = Set<A>();
    }

    public DbSet<A> As { get; private set; }
}
```

AsCached, in the context of linqtocache, is an extension method on IQueryable so  in your code that calls it you can get access to the AsCached property by doing this:

```
using LinqToCache;

namespace MyApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var ctx = new DatabaseContext("ScalabilityTestEntities");

            ctx.As.AsCached("Key").Where(p => p.CategoryID > 0);          
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yes.. I tried downloading that project. It's a jumbled mess just to go ahead and attempt to cache an entity... This link is the easiest way I see of implementing the cache: http://bobhl.blogspot.com/2011/02/caching-in-entity-framework-using-query.html However, in order to do this, you need access to your ObjectContext object which I can't get referring to this link: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/linqprojectgeneral/thread/c99dbc94-e4f2-4459-bf5d-f5fbc959a1a0

Comment: Here is the link that points you to the caching dll to download: http://code.google.com/p/linqtocache/ However, you need access to your Objectcontext object (as explained in my previous comment). I have access to it, but can't get any intellisense after it in order to implement the sqldependency.